# How to implement hierarchical razor template expansion?

Tags: c#, razor, template-engine

I'm using the Razor template engine in a C# console app and trying to expand an object tree to a text file.  I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to get hierarchical expansion to work.

It is probable that I have completely misunderstood how hierarchical template expansion is supposed to work in Razor.  I need to know if my current approach is almost right and just needs fixing, or if I am doing it completely the wrong way, then what is the right way of doing this?

Bonus question: Is Razor the right tool for this or is there a better alternative?

I have created a small test app to demonstrate the problem.  The class `TemplateTreeModel` defines the model that is passed into Razor.  This class defines a tree, the `Children` member is a list of child `TemplateTreeModel` instances.

I want to instance the model and pass it into Razor like this:

```
var model = new TemplateTreeModel();
... add children to the tree ...
var expanded = Razor.Parse(Template, model);
```

`TemplateTreeModel` has a member function `ExpandChildren` that does the hierarchical expansion.  I use it within the template like this:

```
@(Model.ExpandChildren())
```

My test app generates very odd results.  Some of the leaf nodes are repeated in the output and only level 3 nodes are present.  The root node (level 1) and the level 2 nodes are missing from the output.

Update: For some more context on this, the real use case for this is that I want to generate code from an abstract syntax tree.  So I have a bunch of templates that represent the script to output for each AST node.  I then want to expand recursively from the root AST node to translate the AST into a script file.

Following is the full code for the test app.  To get this working you need to put the code in a C# console app and reference RazorEngine (available here http://razorengine.codeplex.com/).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RazorEngine;
using RazorEngine.Templating;

namespace RazorTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class TemplateTreeModel
        {
            private static int nextID = 1;

            public TemplateTreeModel(string template, int level)
            {
                this.Level = level;
                this.ID = nextID++;
                this.Template = template;
                this.Children = new List<TemplateTreeModel>();
            }

            public int Level { get; private set; }
            public int ID { get; private set; }
            public string Template { get; private set; }
            public List<TemplateTreeModel> Children { get; private set; }

            public string ExpandChildren()
            {
                var output = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var child in this.Children)
                {
                    output.Append(child.Expand());
                }

                return output.ToString();
            }

            public string Expand()
            {
                var expanded = Razor.Parse(this.Template, this);
                return expanded;
            }

            public TemplateTreeModel DefineChild(TemplateTreeModel child)
            {
                this.Children.Add(child);
                return this;
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var template = "Node: @Model.ID (Level @Model.Level):\n@(Model.ExpandChildren())\n";
                var root =
                    new TemplateTreeModel(template, 1).
                        DefineChild(
                            new TemplateTreeModel(template, 2).
                                DefineChild(
                                    new TemplateTreeModel(template, 3)
                                ).DefineChild(
                                    new TemplateTreeModel(template, 3)
                                )
                        ).DefineChild(
                            new TemplateTreeModel(template, 2).
                                DefineChild(
                                    new TemplateTreeModel(template, 3)
                                ).DefineChild(
                                    new TemplateTreeModel(template, 3)
                                )
                        );

                var expanded = root.Expand();
                Console.WriteLine(expanded);
            }
            catch (TemplateCompilationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Template compilation errors:");

                foreach (var error in ex.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have moved on from Razor now.  If there is a way to do hierarchical template expansion with Razor then I don't know what it is.

I have however moved over to using the DotLiquid template engine.

http://dotliquidmarkup.org/

It seems pretty good so far, it doesn't seem to support hierarchical template expansion out of the box, although I was able to implement it pretty easily using tags.

Razor would have been nice, especially since it has tight C# integration, DotLiquid does the job though and I like the Django-like syntax.